# Backbone: Form making GET request to the current domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, backbone.js

This is my backbone model:

```
  class @SubscriptionModel extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: (@attributes, @options) ->
```

This is the function I am calling

```
subscribe_event: (event) ->
      event.preventDefault()
      @url = "#{window.location.host}/eventsubscribe/subscribe"
      sub_model = new SubscriptionModel({url : @url})
      sub_model.set({notify_time: $("[name=notify_time]").val(), subscription_type: $("[name=subscription_type]").val(), event_id: $("[name=event_id]").val(), event_domain: $("[name=event_domain]").val()})
      sub_model.save()
      div = $("[name=subscribe_form]")
      div.find('form').remove().end().append("<h4>We'll Keep you posted</h4>")
```

I have bound the form submission event like this.

```
events:
      "submit form.subscribe" : "subscribe_event"
```

My form has all those required fields. But no method is defined.

```
<form class=subscribe>
   ..usual html form stuff
   <button type='submit'>Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

But everytime the form is submitted a GET request is made to the current URL with all the fields in the form.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: i might not understand your question properly, but a `GET` request is the default request of a form unless you change the `method` property of a form.

Comment: Thanks. but how do i call the subscribe_event function on form submit?

Comment: Are you sure the form is within your el/$el/template? If you trying to trigger an event on a DOM element outside the actual view, it will not be captured and thus the preventDefault() will not be called.

Comment: its not in the template. Its a part on the page that pops up after a mouse click event.